# json_encode is not working (anymore)

Tags: php, html, mysql, json, chart.js

So I ran into kind of a weird problem. I am trying to show chart data but the JSON_ENCODE that has to convert my data to JSON is not returning anything. It worked before at the time I had less data but for some reason it not returning anything anymore.

Here's my PHP:

```
$vak = $q->getVakAll();

$data = array();
foreach($vak as $vak){
    $vak = $vak->getCode();
    $result = $q->getAanwezigheidVakkenPerJaar($value, $vak); 
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
}
print json_encode($data);
```

This outputs nothing, the weird thing is when I add this under $data[] = $row:

```
echo $row['vak'];
echo $row['percentage'];
```

It does output something, this:

```
Webdevelopment 176Webdevelopment 224Introductie object georiënteerd programmeren75Multimedia & Design59Informatiestromen73Introductie IT Modelleren6
```

That's what I want to be the output but then JSON encoded, can someone help me?

EDIT:

```
$vak = $q->getVakAll(); //gets all subjects (like webdevelopment)//

$result = $q->getAanwezigheidVakkenPerJaar($value, $vak); //this returns all subjects with their corresponding presence (for example, webdevelopment 1 has a total presence of 74(%)//
```

Comment: What does `$q->getVakAll();` return?

Comment: @Rimble It returns all subjects which contain a value. Like the ones that are being returned in the output

Comment: Is there any conflict with "foreach ($vak as $vak)"?

Comment: Try using `echo json_encode($data);` instead of `print json_encode($data)`

Comment: @hRdCoder not at all, if I return the values via $row[] it works, but it won't convert that data for some reason

Comment: @Lal I have tried that too, no success...

Comment: @sebas2201 Yes I know it returns something, but what _exactly_ how is the array built up, what does `$q->getAanwezigheidVakkenPerJaar($value, $vak);` return? We don't know what those functions do at all.

Comment: Add `echo json_last_error_msg();` at the end...may be that can lead you to somewhere..

Comment: @Lal we're getting somewhere, getting this error: 'Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded'

Comment: You know variables names don't cost that much you can create more then just `$vak` that just confusing. Also the `foreach` might work but on the outside if you use `$vak` expecting that array it will be the last code not an array...

Comment: Also, do a `print_r($result)` for us an show what you have. We need to know what we are working with...

Comment: @sebas2201 convert the text to utf08..you can use `utf8_encode( ) ` in php to convert any string into utf-8 encoding

Comment: @Lal do you have any recommendation for this situation? since $data is an array, another foreach maybe?

Comment: you could try `$data[i]['vak'] = utf8_encode($row['vak']);$data[i]['percentage'] = utf8_encode($row['percentage']);i++;`

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem

```
foreach($vak as $vak)
    $vak = $vak->getCode();
```

You are destroying your `$vak` array in these commands.

Do not reuse the `$vak` variable all over the place. Try this instead.

```
$vaks = $q->getVakAll();

$data = array();
foreach($vaks as $vak){
    $code = $vak->getCode();
    $result = $q->getAanwezigheidVakkenPerJaar($value, $code); 
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `print` use : `echo json__encode(array) die;` hope this help.